# Error passing Datetime as querystring parameter to Servicestack.net GET method

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, servicestack

I trying to pass a DateTime object as a query string parameter to a webservice method built with ServiceStack.net.

The date is properly URL encoded when passed but I keep getting the following error:

```
"Message":"KeyValueDataContractDeserializer: Error converting to type: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

Any ideas of how to correct this?

Here is an example of the URL encoded DateTime I was passing: 2%2f24%2f2012+5%3a13%3a02+PM

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you *have* to pass datetimes as strings, try to pass them in an unambiguous format. I assume you're tying to pass the 24th February 2012, 17:13:02 - something like the following would be unambiguous:

```
2012-02-24T17:13:02
```

E.g. if you're [formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) the date in .NET, use "o" or "s"

---

This is *nothing* to do with URL encoding - it's to do with passing data unambiguously - dates such as 01/02/2012 can be interpreted at least two ways - 1st February or 2nd January of this year, for two.

Comment: This sounds like a good solution but I am still unable to parse a valid date from 2012-02-24T17:13:02 when it is url encoded

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at having the websservice accept a string parameter and then using DateTime.Parse or DateTime.TryParse to convert the string to a DateTime?